# HTML and CSS Background change

Tags: html, css

I require some help. My friend sent me an HTML document and he asked me to change the background. Now I'm new to HTML and all this but changing the background should be easy but I can't find it anywhere in the HTML doc or the CSS. Any help?

Comment: need to see code mate.

Comment: Use the css `background-color` property. This should be easy to find if you do some research yourself, for example by googling 'CSS background', which gets you many results. If on the other hand you've tried this already and it didn't work, we need to see your code to solve the problem.

Comment: @BalvantAhir added the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The background image can be inserted in the page using the below within body tag or by using CSS: **< div style="background-image:url('[image url]');>**

Also, this website contain good information to go through : https://www.wikihow.com/Set-a-Background-Image-in-HTML

Answer (score 1):

Just create a new css for example for body like this if you want it to be black:

```
     body {
     background: #000000;
     }
```

That should work.

Comment: Its an image and I need to change the image out for a new one

Comment: Then like this: background: #000 url(/images/background.png);

Answer (score 1):

```css
div{
   background-image: url("https://homepages.cae.wisc.edu/~ece533/images/tulips.png");
   height:100px;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: worked but only for 2 bits of the section so I don't know if there is an image in front but i cant find it so?

Comment: @BenHoward Please indicate your code to your question above. So that we can help you here. Thanks

Comment: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1zG2sJR-TWNOzawi8jq_YP254FyntIB3B

Answer (score 1):

Add a style for `header` in your CSS file :

```
.header {
  background: "#000000"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can change the background by using background-color or background-image as follows:

```
<div style="background-color: red" >
This div has a background-color of red
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The HTML file contains 2 main sections - `<head>, <body>`.

Head specifies attributes like page title, language, links to stylesheets (css / designs).

'***Background***' can be applied to any part within the `<body>` section of the HTML file (including body).

**Background can be applied in 2 ways -**

1. A colour - Using `style="background-color: color-code;"`
2. An image - Using `style="background-image: url('img_girl.jpg')"`

Here is an example of background being applied:

**Approach 1:  Background colour:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>My Website</title>
  </head>
  <body style="background-color: #e6f2ff;">
    <div class="my-page">
      <h1>-- Heading here --</h2>
      <p>-- Description here -- </p>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

**Approach 2:  Background image:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>My Website</title>
  </head>
  <body style="background-image: url("/paper.gif");">
    <div class="my-page">
      <h1>-- Heading here --</h2>
      <p>-- Description here -- </p>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

**Note:**
The background color / image can be applied to any element inside body, I.E., to div / h1 / p ...

**More information:**

https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-image.asp

https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_images_background.asp